# Longest word in List

Tags: list, scala

I have a List with Strings and I want to print the longest String out of it

I have tried the `reduceLeft` option but whenever I am applying it its returning this error:

```
type mismatch; found:String required:Ordering[?]
```

Here is the code throwing the exception in the second line:

```
val input2 = List("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
for (entry <- input2.reduceLeft(_ max _)) println(input2.max)
```

Comment: I removed large parts of the question, because they seemed not relevant. Feel free to revert.

Comment: No need to revert, seems far better now and compact! Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should ask yourself: What is the *max* for a list of Strings?
`List[String].max` and `String.max` need more clarification for their task.

1. use `List.maxBy` instead of `List.reduceLeft`

   ```
   input2.maxBy(_.length)
   ```
2. use implicit type conversion

   ```
   implicit def string2ordering(s: String) = s.length
   input2.max
   ```

Answer (score 4):

As so often you have tons of options in Scala. The easiest I can come up with, is to us `maxBy` as already suggested by @user925723

```
val input2 = List("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

println(
  input2.maxBy(_.length)
)
```

maxBy returns the maximum of a collection, but you have to define what you mean by maximum. The "largest" String can be defined by its positon in the alphabet, the first time it was used in literature or as in your case by its length. Scala doesn't know, so you have to tell it, by providing a conversion to something that has a standard ordering (`int`s in this example)

If you want to use reduceLeft, you can use the following

```
println(
  input2.reduce(
    (a, b) =>
      if (a.length < b.length)
        b
      else
        a
  )
)
```

So what is wrong with your approach:

1. I'm not sure which max function you are using, but it is probably comparing Strings by the alphabet.
2. reduceLeft returns a value of the element type of the collection. That would be a String. If you iterate over a String, you are iterating over the characters of the string, not what you want.
3. Finally for each character of a String, you are printing the max of the collection.
4. I'm actually not sure what caused the compiler exception, it might be that max is looking for some implicit conversion to something with an Ordering and didn't find it, but I'm not to sure about it.

Which brings me to a third variant: define an implicite conversion to Ordering and than use max.

```
implicit def string2ordering(s : String) = s.length
println(
  input2.max
)
```